# "Cannot GET /explorer" error in composer after running the composer-rest-server command

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

> Discovering types from business network definition ...
>
> Discovering the Returning Transactions..
>
> Discovered types from business network definition
>
> Generating schemas for all types in business network definition ...
>
> Generated schemas for all types in business network definition
>
> Adding schemas for all types to Loopback ...
>
> Added schemas for all types to Loopback
>
> Web server listening at: `http://localhost:3000`

Then when I run the above link in browser, I am getting the error as:

> {"error":{"statusCode":404,"name":"Error","message":"Cannot GET /explorer/","status":404,"stack":"Error: Cannot GET /explorer/\n    at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:21:17)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)\n    at /home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n    at Function.process_params (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)\n    at next (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n    at /home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15\n    at next (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)\n    at Function.handle (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)\n    at router (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)\n    at /home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n    at Function.process_params (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)\n    at next (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n    at urlencodedParser (/home/santosh/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:91:7)"}}

Comment: You probably said No to having the explorer test interface when answering the questions about what features you want on your rest server.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar error after the command `composer-rest-server`. I solved mine by

1. Quitting the current instance using `Ctrl + C`
2. Rerun the command `composer-rest-server`
3. Typing in `Yes` (or y) for the question `? Specify if you want to enable the explorer test interface:`

Specifying the key for dynamic logging didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

After the command `composer-rest-server`, the terminal asks some questions about how to configure the server.[questions asked for configuring server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMwqO.png)

For the question, `Specify a key if you want to enable dynamic logging?` if you don't want to specify any key then type `No`. Typing `n` or leaving blank, it takes that as key.Restart the server and then type `No`. Hope it works.